# Our set of tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

Well chosen tags improve the experience of the site regarding browsing and searching. If we would create some guidelines regarding tag names, we could get more consistent tags and avoid creating too much synonyms.

Here are some suggestions, how tag names could be chosen:

- Doing and how-to: [routing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing), [switching](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switching), [testing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) (the -ing form, gerund, would be nice)
- Concepts and protocols: [spanning-tree](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanning-tree), [vss](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vss), [qos](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qos), [ospf](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ospf), [mpls](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mpls)
- Things: [interfaces](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces), [firewalls](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firewalls) (plural preferred)
- Hardware and manufacturers: [cisco](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco), [juniper](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juniper)

I suggest we better create basic tags, which built the tag list of a question, instead of very specific long tags consisting of words and dashes. Let's keep in mind that for searching tags can be combined, so a user can combine the manufacturer [cisco](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco) with [mpls](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mpls) as protocol, so no need for [cisco-mpls](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco-mpls).

I speak about rough guidelines, meaning conventions like plural and gerund. Also here it's not always easy to decide whether to use one or the other, for example [routing](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing) for working with routing but [routers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routers) for hardware discussions - may be good to have both, clearly distinguished in their tag wiki explanation, or in similar cases to decide for one.

While thinking of tags, let's keep in mind that at some time we may have a thousand tags and more.

Comment: Also, there was some discussion about using the general series names -- [tag:cisco-catalyst] rather than specific model numbers 'cisco-2924' or series numbers 'cisco-2900', since they can be confusing; eg, 2900 series is also numbers for Cisco ISR-G2 routers.

Comment: +1 for series tags. Cisco, for example, is enormously varied across it's device families.

Comment: @SJG for clarity: I was saying do NOT use NUMERICAL series tags. For example, for Cisco gear, numerical series numbers are not unique, 2900 can be Catalyst gear or routers. Thus [tag:cisco-catalyst] and [tag:cisco-isr-g2]

Comment: I agree - a series may be long in use, but a specific model number may quickly become outdated. Otherwise we would collect a *lot* of numbered tags. Still a user can combine series tag with number in text search.